# In Django template built-in filter "date", what does the format "o" mean?

Tags: django

I'm looking the Django version 2.1. From the document, the date format template built-in filter has an `o` format which is described as the following:

"ISO-8601 week-numbering year, corresponding to the ISO-8601 week number (W) which uses leap weeks. See Y for the more common year format."

I don't quite understand this. I tried it with the date `2018-12-31`, it outputs '2019'.

The document is here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Can anyone explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to provide some relevant insight: https://www.epochconverter.com/weeknumbers

Comment: Read up on leap weeks? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_week_calendar